# How to get self.value from an inherited class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this two classes that I needed to divide, though they share some common features. Is it possible to access first class' **self.value** from the second class? Please look at the pseudo code, surely more understandable then my words.

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 45

class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        self.other_value = #this should be self.value from class a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need call the parent constructor first

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should call the parent constructor:

```
class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        a.__init__(self)
        #now you can use it with self.value
```